# ArcGIS Online - Related table not displaying at all in popup

Tags: arcgis-online

1. I created a file gdb and imported both the table and shapefile.
2. Added them to the ArcMap table of contents and created a relate.
3. Published as a service & ensured all was correct in the dialog box.
4. I've added the layer to a basemap in ArcGIS Online.

Both the feature layer & related table show up in the contents however as shown in the picture below the option to "show related tables" is not available which is what I need.

[image]

Comment: I believe you have to create a relationship class in a geodatabase, not a relate inside the ArcMap map document

Comment: Also check the feature service to see if there is any relationship info in each of the layers.

Comment: There is a [Query Related Records Application](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=79fbfec59568446b9f46eea343a5dd59) you can download and customize to display the information. As @AlexTereshenkov mentions - you will need to build the relationship class inside the gdb first and not in the application.

Comment: Hi, guys!! How do you build the relationship inside the gbd?? I can't seem to find any options to do so :/ Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you GDB you right click new relationship class also when you add your feature in AGOL you need to add the relate table and it will show when you do identify.
[image: Relationship GDB]